# How do I get rid of the bullets next to my twitter feed?

Tags: css, wordpress

Hi there I have a twitter feed on the homepage I'm working on at the moment. I can't get rid of the bullets. I can't find the correct CSS code to enter the line "list-style-type: none;"

I've searched for ages! Please help!

www.playlistforlife.org.uk/wordpress

Thanks

P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because they are being added as pseudo :before elements, not with `list-style` (which is the more typical way of adding bullet points). Look at line 1379 of style.css and you'll see the block of code that is adding them. Either comment them out, or add `display:none`

For the sake of learning, here's the block of CSS that is adding those bullets:

**CSS - style.css**

```
 .post-content ul li:before {
    content: "\2022";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: #a0a0a0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
```